# Can't connect to Docker daemon in my GitLab CI pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I am trying to build a super-simple CI/CD pipeline using GitLab CI.
Upon running it I get presented with the error:

```
Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375.
Is the docker daemon running?
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml is :

```
image: docker:latest
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]
    command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]


before_script:
  - docker --version
docker_build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build -t arieltar/hubsec:1.1 .
    - docker push arieltar/hubsec:1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message I would ask, does the `gitlab-runner` user belong to the `docker` group?

You will need to decide if you want to use Docker-in-Docker with, or without TLS. This requires changing `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` settings, and assigning the `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. See the [Docker-in-docker section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker) of the GitLab docs.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below things as prelim.

1. Whether docker is running or not
2. Login with gitlab-user if you are running pipeline with gitlab user and check if that user can access or run docker ps without sudo :).
3. add below entry if pt1. and pt2 satisfied.

services:

- name: docker:dind
  entrypoint: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh", "--tls=false"]
  script:
- export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 && docker build -t arieltar/hubsec:1.1 .